# exit (SystemExit) error with ruby on rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, dreamhost

My website is currently down after dreamhost upgraded their server system. I had to install bundler which installed successfully and when I ftp'd the site to the server the error coder fell about 100 lines to what it looks like now.

The error code is:

```
exit (SystemExit)
  /home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/boot.rb:65:in `exit'
  /home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/boot.rb:65:in `load_rails_gem'
  /home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/boot.rb:53:in `load_initializer'
  /home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/boot.rb:110:in `run'
  /home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
  /home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/boot.rb:127
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/environment.rb:16
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:184
Error ID

787dc4fa
```

here's the config/boot.rb file

```rb
# Don't change this file!
# Configure your app in config/environment.rb and config/environments/*.rb

RAILS_ROOT = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/.." unless defined?(RAILS_ROOT)

module Rails
  class << self
    def boot!
      unless booted?
        preinitialize
        pick_boot.run
      end
    end

    def booted?
      defined? Rails::Initializer
    end

    def pick_boot
      (vendor_rails? ? VendorBoot : GemBoot).new
    end

    def vendor_rails?
      File.exist?("#{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/rails")
    end

    def preinitialize
      load(preinitializer_path) if File.exist?(preinitializer_path)
    end

    def preinitializer_path
      "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/preinitializer.rb"
    end
  end

  class Boot
    def run
      load_initializer
      Rails::Initializer.run(:set_load_path)
    end
  end

  class VendorBoot < Boot
    def load_initializer
      require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer"
      Rails::Initializer.run(:install_gem_spec_stubs)
    end
  end

  class GemBoot < Boot
    def load_initializer
      self.class.load_rubygems
      load_rails_gem
      require 'initializer'
    end

    def load_rails_gem
      if version = self.class.gem_version
        gem 'rails', version
      else
        gem 'rails'
      end
    rescue Gem::LoadError => load_error
      $stderr.puts %(Missing the Rails #{version} gem. Please `gem install -v=#{version} rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.)
      exit 1
    end

    class << self
      def rubygems_version
        Gem::RubyGemsVersion rescue nil
      end

      def gem_version
        if defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
          RAILS_GEM_VERSION
        elsif ENV.include?('RAILS_GEM_VERSION')
          ENV['RAILS_GEM_VERSION']
        else
          parse_gem_version(read_environment_rb)
        end
      end

      def load_rubygems
        require 'rubygems'
        min_version = '1.3.1'
        unless rubygems_version >= min_version
          $stderr.puts %Q(Rails requires RubyGems >= #{min_version} (you have #{rubygems_version}). Please `gem update --system` and try again.)
          exit 1
        end

      rescue LoadError
        $stderr.puts %Q(Rails requires RubyGems >= #{min_version}. Please install RubyGems and try again: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org)
        exit 1
      end

      def parse_gem_version(text)
        $1 if text =~ /^[^#]*RAILS_GEM_VERSION\s*=\s*["']([!~<>=]*\s*[\d.]+)["']/
      end

      private
        def read_environment_rb
          File.read("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/environment.rb")
        end
    end
  end
end

class Rails::Boot
  def run
    load_initializer
    extend_environment
    Rails::Initializer.run(:set_load_path)
  end

  def extend_environment
    Rails::Initializer.class_eval do
      old_load = instance_method(:load_environment)
      define_method(:load_environment) do
        Bundler.require :default, Rails.env
        old_load.bind(self).call
      end
    end
  end
end

# All that for this:
Rails.boot!
```

Comment: What is in your `/home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/boot.rb` especially at line 65? My boot.rb only has 2 lines of code...

Comment: @2called-chaos Looks like it's 2-ish Rails. And also, Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

From what I dug out in old Rails branches, your Rails version is around 2.1-2.2, judging from the [boot.rb file's line 65](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-1-stable/railties/environments/boot.rb#L65). And it should've printed the exact version number and the warning that it's not installed. Also, version 2 seems not to use Bundler, so you'll have to install the gem with regular rubygems. Try to find out what exact Rails version your app is and run

```
gem install -v 2.x.x rails
```

And also an advise: your users don't need to see the Passenger's debugging info. If you can, configure it to write the details to log file while showing a brief error page to users. Because Passenger is being too verbose right now on your page. I can predict all kinds of security problems from this behaviour.

Comment: currently the sites down to a syntax error that looks like this
/home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/boot.rb:90: syntax error, unexpected kRESCUE, expecting kEND
       rescue LoadError
             ^ (SyntaxError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /home/studioanisewm/studioanise.com/config/environment.rb:16

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:184

Comment: Did you edit your boot.rb manually? Looks like somebody broke it after you original question, because then it was parsed without any syntax errors. Can you roll back the changes made to boot.rb and install the rails gem as I suggested?

Comment: I did and Ill try fixing it like that now

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 2.x.x) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rails

Comment: I also added the config/boot.rb lines 88 to end

Comment: No, you need to find out what exact version of Rails did your application use, and enter it instead. May be in your environment.rb in RAILS_GEM_VERSION constant.

Comment: Did you roll back your changes to boot.rb? It looks okay, but it may be broken above line 88. I strongly advise you not to edit any files unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: i ran the gem install -v 2.3.5 rails and then FTP'd the site to check and so far theres no change

Comment: I've attached the full config/boot.rb file

Comment: How do you make sure you have the gem installed on the server correctly? From what Passenger tell, gems have to be installed under `/home/studioanisewm/.gems` is there the rails gem? Also, what do you mean by "FTP-ing the site"?

Comment: this is the first attempt i've had with ruby
I install gems via /Users/...../Desktop/studioanise.com in terminal

i upload the site to the server via filezilla

Comment: You have to install gems on the server. I guess you can try to upload your local gems folder to `/home/studioanisewm/.gems`

Comment: for some reason there is no directory for /home/studioanisewm on the ftp server

Comment: There is indeed. Passenger shows that your app is under that path. Most likely, when you connect to FTP, `/home/studioanisewm` is your root path. You probably should consult with support of your hosting, if they broke your app with thier upgrade, they should know how to fix it.